# Adwords conversions on overview vs conversions on conversion actions

Tags: google-ads

We have google analytics tracking conversions and noticed quite a difference between the conversions analytics is tracking versus the conversions google adwords is tracking.

I found out that the conversions found in analytics compare to the conversions found in the conversion action in adwords.

In the screenshot below you can see 34 conversions.
The conversion action only has 2 conversions though.
The description of the field tells me it is based on conversion action which are taken in to account (which should be 2 conversions) and the amount of time the conversion action can be fired per person which is set to 1.

Where are these other 32 conversions coming from?

[image: Conversion overview]

Comment: If you have call extenstion or call ads, google count calls as conevrsion